# ModuleNotFoundError VSCode Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have create a virtual environment using

```
py -m venv C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\venv
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install matplotlib
```

But when I run the code it shows ModuleNotFoundError:

[image]

But if I run `python testing.py` in terminal it works, not sure why.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

If using the global enviroment it works fine.

Comment: You did not activate the virtual environment in VS Code.

Comment: I think I should have selected the corret interpreter path, does it mean it is activated?

Comment: Sry i stuck in th estep 3 solution I could not found the Files:Association, and JSON: Schemas section

Comment: I think the virtual enviroment should have activated as beside the terminal there is a green (venv)?

Comment: I am here to update my progress, I have give up to use VScode for coding Python, I now using pycharm and the enviroment problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the folder containing venv folder when you "Open Folder..". VS Code includes the included venv by default as the virtual environment. This is the simplest method that works for me

Comment: Yes the venv folder is alrdy in my project folder but it still showing the problem

Comment: the python environment is at the bottom right in blue bar. What env are you getting there. can you click on that to see if you change the interpreter?

Comment: Yes i have seleced the venv i created and the path is 
.\venv\Scripts\python.ese

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are using **Code Runner** to execute the script, which is wrong. You should use the official extension **Python** to execute the script.

The `Select Interpreter` panel and show python version on the lower right corner are features of Python extensions. You have selected the interpreter of the virtual environment, which is only valid for **Python** extensions. And you use **Code Runner** to execute the script, it will only use the python version configured in the environment variable, so you still get the error.

So you now have two solutions:

- Choose the correct interpreter and execute the script with the **Python** extension

  [image]
- Install the `numpy` and `matplotlib` package for the interpreter used by **Code Runner**.

*You can verify which interpreter is being used with*

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```